# Drupal7 : content type with many fields

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, field, cck

what's the best way in Drupal 7 to handle many fields (> 40).
I've to handle hostels content-type.
D7 creates as many mysql tables as fields count, so I fear for the performances, but maybe it's not a problem.

Do I have to create entity and sub-entities or create modules to store some data in the same table (a field for equipments, a field for services, a field for activites, etc.)
or other solution ?

Many thanks for your advices !

Answer (score 1):

40 fields are not that bad as I have seem plenty db tables with more fields.

Drupal is not really that good in OO and normalization but you can:

- Create multiple custom content type and link them via [Corresponding Node References](http://drupal.org/project/cnr) to mimic the entity relationship, foreign key.
- use [taxonomy](http://drupal.org/node/1146844)
- write you own module never hurts as it help you learn the Druapl way.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

You can leave it as is, because, you know, between performance and flexibility, Drupal chose flexibility:)

if you want to have all these stored in 1 table, it's possible to write module that implements custom fieldset, like this: http://www.lullabot.com/articles/creating-custom-cck-fields
however, it's for D6 - I haven't done similar thing for D7 with cck fields in core, so can't give you direction here.

I guess, [this](http://drupal.org/node/707832) and particularly [this](http://www.figover.com/node/15) might help.